# How to add unmanned jars directory to specif profile in Maven with out install

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar, classpath

I want to add my jars library which is c:\tmp\jars\ (more than 100 jars files) to specific profile in Maven with out installing. 
Installing each jar in maven and adding each dependency is not i'm looking.

I'm using Intellij and Maven

I can add the jar directory by project module settings add Jars but its applicable to all profiles, i want add this jars to specific profile.[image]

for example y project has 2 profiles hdp,azure
for hdp profile the external jars not required but azure profile the external jar required.

Agian I don't want to install in maven add each dependency is not my option.

Comment: You need to configure this in Maven. Check this approach: http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/ Then make sure it actually works when you build by Maven from command line.

Answer (score 1):

If the jars are not listed as dependencies in your POM, Maven cannot see them.

Even if IntelliJ sees them, you get a strange hybrid project that Maven cannot build any more.